useEffect does not work in production build NextJS
useEffect does not work in production build. following is the code snippet
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect 1")
    return () => {
      console.log("useeffect 2")
    };
  }, [])

In development useEffect triggering multiple times and the result is
useeffect 1
useeffect 2
useeffect 1


but In Production build the result is
useeffect 1

is this expected or not
step 1
npx create-next-app@latest 
step 2
'use client'
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect 1")
    return () => {
      console.log("useeffect 2")
    };
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>TEST</div>
  );
}


step 3 run in development mode
npm run dev
step 4 run production build
npm run build
npm run start

Probably <StrictMode>

by adding  reactStrictMode: false  in next.config worked like prod mode

Yes, this is expected assuming you are using React 18 or above. There's this video where the speaker mentions the same issue. Link to the video. I assume your clean-up is not called because your component is not unmounted otherwise this is not an expected behavior.

In development mode (npm run dev), Next.js employs a hot module replacement (HMR) mechanism. When a component changes, the entire component tree is recreated, causing useEffect to run again. This leads to the repeated "useeffect 1" and "useeffect 2" logs. In production mode (npm run build followed by npm run start), Next.js pre-renders the components on the server during the build process. This static rendering optimizes performance but prevents useEffect from running on subsequent client-side re-renders, resulting in only the initial "useeffect 1" log.
